# Trying to run javascript with a href for validation

Tags: javascript, html

At the bottom of my webpage, I have a submit button. I've used this code:

```
<a onClick="myFunction(); return false;" href="testpage.html">Submit</a>
```

What I'm trying to do is when my function is called, I'm checking for validation. If it's false, my function raises an alert and the user doesn't leave the current page...which is what I want. When its true though...nothing changes. When it's true I want them to go to the next link.

```
function myFunction() {
            if (localStorage.length != 3) {
                alert("Missing Values");
            } else {
                break;
            } 
        }
```

It goes to the next link when I put in break, but now the alert doesn't get called even if it's requirements are met. Moreover, whey does the break in the else block get called even when the if block requirements are met?

Comment: keyword `break` cannot be used outside the loop.

Comment: This comment is actually the answer. `break` is not called, nothing was executed, because a syntax error was thrown, and everything stops.

Comment: I'm new to js, and have used python in the past. If break is in the else block, is it not still inside the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well return false cancels the action. So if you do not want to stop the link, you need to remove that.

```
<a onclick="return myFunction();" href="testpage.html">Submit</a>
```

Now return true or false from myFunction

```
function myFunction() {
    if (localStorage.length != 3) {
        alert("Missing Values");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your html to `<a onClick="myFunction()" href="testpage.html">Submit</a>` and function to:

```
function myFunction() {
  if (localStorage.length != 3) {
     event.preventDefault();
  } 
}
```

See Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/L0q7ocgg/